# Unknown tag (form:option) error

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

why am I getting unknown tag for

```
 <form:option >
 <form:form method="post" >
```

in spring mvc. How can I solve this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to import the form tag. add this to your jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

also, the `form:option` should be inside a `select`:

```
<form:select path="mySelect">
    <form:option value="0" label="A" />
    <form:option value="1" label="B" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: what should be the path? I can't proceed without declaring path

Comment: the path is the name of field in your `@ModelAttribute`-Bean. Check this: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

Comment: Reference is helpful. Thanks